# Как узнать, какая кодировка должна применяться к файлу в Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, кодировка

У меня был файл, в котором часть комментариев на русском отображалась нормально, часть не распознавалась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда у файла была кодировка `windows-1251`. После того, как я изменила кодировку файла на `UTF-8`, все комментарии стали нечитаемыми:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как узнать, какая кодировка должна быть у файла?
Т.е., может, есть какие-нибудь алгоритмы наподобие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, да, онлайн-декодерами я время от времени пользуюсь, но я надеялась, что есть какой-нибудь 100%-ный способ узнать правильную (изначальную) кодировку именно для одного файла Intellij Idea

Comment: это чистый рандом на самом деле, все эти анализаторы просто перебирают кодировки и проверяет соответствие частоты появления символов в тексте и средней частоты для заданного языка. Они имеют вероятностую природу. 100% вам никто не даст. P.S. в idea я смотрю плагинов такого рода нет.

Comment: Если одни комментарии отображаются правильно, а другие нет, значит там смесь кодировок и одной правильной кодировки просто не может быть.

Comment: @Roman какая то очень странная ситуация, но очень может быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В идеале используется кодировка `UTF-8.`
Если вы хотите сохранить файл в UTF-8 c комментариями, но не переписывая их: 
Можно восстановить кодировку `Windows-1251`, выделить все, вырезать, поменять кодировку на `UTF-8` и вставить вырезанное. Таким образом у Вас будет файл в формате `UTF-8` и сохранятся комментарии на кириллице.

Для декодирования можете воспользоваться [вот этим сервисом.](http://foxtools.ru/Text)

Comment: А как узнать, в какой кодировке должен быть нижний комментарий, который изначально был в неправильной кодировке?

Comment: @Ksenia Ну Вы говорите, что у Вас комментарии корректно отображались в кодировке windows-1251. P.S. В большинстве своем, если кодировка у файла меняется на UTF-8 и там была кириллица - символы заменяются на ?. Так что попробуйте метод, который я описал выше.

Comment: Я писала "часть комментариев на русском отображалась нормально" :)

Comment: @Ksenia прикрепил к ответу ссылку на сервис, который распознает текст в неизвестной кодировке. Попробуйте при помощи него подобрать.

Comment: А точного способа узнать правильную (изначальную) кодировку именно для одного файла Intellij Idea нет?

Comment: Т.е., может, есть какая-нибудь история изменений именно кодировок?)

Comment: @Ksenia точные способы к сожалению отсутствуют. И истории изменений кодировок также нет.